# How to prevent HTML div injection from being overridden by website CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a Chrome extension that injects some HTML to display a popup overlay at the location of user highlighted text. It works as intended on most websites, but on some websites (notably [ESPN](https://www.espn.com)) the overlay CSS I've written is getting overridden by the default website CSS.

I've created id tags for each of my elements to have more specific CSS selectors but visually nothing has changed. I've also tried using !important, despite being bad practice, but that also has not affected anything.

Here's my code for creating the overlay:

```
function setupOverlay() {
  overlayDOM = document.createElement("div");
  overlayDOM.setAttribute("id", "selection_overlay");
  statsTable = document.createElement("table");
  statsTable.setAttribute("id", "selection_table");
  overlayDOM.appendChild(statsTable);
  document.body.appendChild(overlayDOM);
}
```

Here's a portion of the CSS for the overlay:

```css
#selection_overlay {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2147483647;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: solid 2px;
  border-color: #808080;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px #404040;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
  background-color: rgba(75, 75, 75, 0.95);
}

#selection_table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: Why are they being crossed out? What CSS selector is overriding them?

Comment: My mistake, some lines were struck out because they could potentially be changed in my content.js file, not by other CSS selectors. I'm not sure why the popup overlay appears differently on specific websites then.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like ESPN uses some styles that affect table elements:

```
table td:first-child {
    text-align: left;
}
table td {
    color: #48494a;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    height: 28px;
    line-height: 1.2;
    padding: 1px 4px 0 4px;
    margin: 0;
    text-transform: none;
    white-space: nowrap;

}
table th, table td {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Since your Table children elements aren't explicitly called out, this may be what's overriding your settings.  I suggest specifically styling all elements such as:

```
#selection_table td {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```